# How to create multiple step posting (like Instagram) on iOS, Swift, using Xcode instead of code where it makes sense

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I got:

Click + -> Post screen pops up, from bottom; click Next -> another screen pops up, from bottom.

But I can't:

1. Make the 2nd screen appear from right, as would be expected from clicking a button called Next on iOS.
2. Have < Back button on 2nd screen.
3. Make contents inputted in 1st and 2nd screens go to where I want them to go (this might be more than what you can answer given it requires a lot of explanation but adding it just in case).

Help would be much appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing everything modally. Look at using a `UINavigationController` with `Push` segues. [Apple documentation for UINavigationController` here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)

Comment: Thank you, I have added a comment below the answer by alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Storyboard you could do the following:
You've got `ViewController A` (say its the initial ViewController). Pressing the '+' button makes `ViewController B` appear from the bottom (presentModally).
Now you want a 'Next' button in the top right corner that makes `ViewController C` appear from the right, am i right?
Select ViewController B and select **Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller**
Next, select the segue between `ViewController B` and `C` and set 'Kind' to `Show (e.g Push)`.
That should do the trick, `ViewController C` should appear from the right and should have a **< Back** button.

**EDIT:**
_________.........._________........._________..........._________
|________|..........|________|..........|________|..........|_________|
____A__->modal__NavVC___->______B___->push____C

A contains the '+' button, B contains the 'Next' button

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Alexander. I should have added, I tried this but it added a new navigation controller between B and the existing navigation controller A (that connects view A + B) without creating view C. Manually created view C and connected it with manually-created button Next with Show (e.g. push) but still C popped up from bottom. All other options (popover, etc.) same.

Comment: Yes thats right, in order to present C with a push segue you need B to be embeded in a navigation controller

Comment: Now it the screen appears distorted on simulator with error message upon clicking +. Currently View A -> Nav Controller A -> Nav Controller B -> View B -> View C. (embedding nav controller by clicking on B created Nav B between Nav A and view B). I manually created view C and connected Next button on View B with C.

Comment: OK, I think the reason your instruction didn't work was that on my storyboard there was already a view controller A between view A and B (to make B present modally) and embedding a new nav controller from B created a new one between A and B.